# How to add a stored procedure that returns a scalar value to Entity Framework model and call it from the Entity Context?

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a scalar value, I mapped it in the entity model, created an imported function, however it wasn't add into the context class. So I was not able to found how to call it from C# code.

Thanks in advance,
Carlos Loth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EF 1, it's [a little involved](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/implement-select-stored-procedures-that-return-miscellaneous-data-in-ctp2-of-ef-designer/).

In EF 4, [this is directly supported.](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-big-step-for-stored-procedures-in-ef4/)

Answer (score 0):

This is 2013, with EF Beta 6 AND STILL, we cannot achieve this. Different to what ^ Craig ^ Responded, you can get a "COLLECTION" of thingies rather than the thingy itself. They DID change this in EF 5 (WARNING: snarky comment comming), they changed the UI to say "Returns a Collection Of".

As UGLY as it may seem, I sometimes create EF_SP_foo wrappers that all they do is a "SELECT" for the scalar value and return it with a Standarized name "Result"

```
CREATE EF_SP_foo
    @ID bigint
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @newID bigint
EXEC @newID = SP_foo @ID

      SELECT @newID AS Result  -- I really hate this part
  END
```

- UPDATE *
  Although, if you DON'T specify Return type, it will be treated as an INT function (used mainly for rowcounts or State IDs to return I suppose)